# 'This' Selector in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I am dynamically creating a page (in VB) and thus have a number of elements with the same class. I need to animate these individually, not as a group. I have done this in the past with the `this` selector. But I can't seem to get it functioning now.

```
$(".img").on("mouseover", function () {
  $(".img").animate({
    right: '75px',
    speed: 'fast'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the string selector with `this`

```
$(".img").on("mouseover", function () {
  $(this).animate({
    right: '75px',
    speed: 'fast'
  });
});
```

Inside the handler, `this` will be the specific `.img` instance in which the mouse hovered